# Clipping low resolution raster using ModelBuilder of ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, modelbuilder, clip

I am using ArcMap 10.7.1.

The raster dataset I want to clip is of low resolution (cell size: 0.5 degrees). When I clip or extract by mask, the output raster edges are jagged and does not fit to the exact boundary shape.

How can I avoid jagged edges in the output layer?

I tried "clip" option in "Image Analysis" window and it worked. It clips exactly to the shape of the boundary. Input raster cell size: 0.5 degrees and after clipping, output layer cell size: 0.5 degrees.

But, there are lots of such raster that I have to clip.

How can I incorporate "Image Analysis" tools in ModelBuilder or Python console?

The python snippet for "jagged clipping" is:

```
arcpy.Clip_management(in_raster="tmax", rectangle="81.8328623341264 18.6388045795523 86.9858676198333 22.8395249343084", out_raster="C:/Users/bk/Documents/ArcGIS/Default1.gdb/tmax_View_Clip1", in_template_dataset="Boundary_Reprojected", nodata_value="9.990000e+01", clipping_geometry="ClippingGeometry", maintain_clipping_extent="MAINTAIN_EXTENT")
```

No python snippet was found for "clip exactly". I have attached a snapshot for reference.

[image]

Comment: A coarse raster is a jagged object. It cannot be smoothed. It can be oversampled into a fine raster. Are you certain your processing performed the task you want? Fine rasters use more storage than coarse ones.  Please [Edit] the Question to provide information about the pixel dimensions of the source and output images.

Comment: Pixel dimensions of source and output images is provided @Vince

Comment: Graphics of your "jagged" and "clips exactly" results, and the exact geoprocessing commands for the two (as shown in Geoprocessing->Results->(result)->Copy as Python Snippet) might be needed to explain the problem.

Comment: the python snippet and a snapshot of image analysis>clip is attached. No python snippet was found for image analysis>clip @Vince

Comment: In general, how can I use a raster function in model builder?